# standard process after ingesting data in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

I am importing the data from oracle to Hadoop and then i want to keep that data into hive.

1. what are the steps to be followed after ingesting the data into hadoop?
2. How to perform data cleaning or error check in ingested data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *1. what are the steps to be followed after ingesting the data into hadoop?*

You don't need to do it yourself (*importing data to hadoop then transferring to hive*)

As per [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive),

You just need to add `--hive-import` in your import command.

**Change hive table**

> The table name used in Hive is, by default, the same as that of the source table. You can control the output table name with the `--hive-table` option.

**overwrite hive table**

> If the Hive table already exists, you can specify the `--hive-overwrite` option to indicate that existing table in hive must be replaced

@sachin mentioned handling of NULL values in data. You can check the [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) for more details

### *2. How to perform data cleaning or error check in ingested data?*

I assume from "data cleaning" you mean cleaning data in hadoop.

> After your data is imported into HDFS or this step is omitted, Sqoop will generate a Hive script containing a `CREATE TABLE` operation defining your columns using Hive’s types, and a `LOAD DATA INPATH` statement to move the data files into Hive’s warehouse directory.

Data is moved to Hive. So, no data in temporary HDFS location.

Some of the common issues are mentioned in [Troubleshooting docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_troubleshooting). You can check that for basis errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can ingest data directly from oracle to hive table using sqoop with optimize connector called Oraoop.For data cleaning I assume you mean treating null values if that is the case you can use different options provided by sqoop like

```
--null-string <null-string>     
--null-non-string <null-string>
```